# Dynamic list not maping from json Data

Tags: flutter, dart

## Dynamic list not maping from json Data

```
var jsondata = [
{
  'value': '1',
  'label': 'Red',
},
{
  'value': '2',
  'label': 'Green',
},
{
  'value': '3',
  'label': 'Yellow',
},
];


List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = jsondata;
```

#### JSON Data not maping as variable with `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_serializabl` to parse JSON.

The document of official can teach you to do this.

Sample code from the document of official

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(jsonString);

print('Howdy, ${user['name']}!');
print('We sent the verification link to ${user['email']}.');
```

Ref: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: The argument type 'List<Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: You have to use `for-loop` to process your each object of the array

Comment: I am not sure about your problem. Your code can run without the error. https://dartpad.dev/?id=e74ebbd6c5a74bb80b0d7dfb397bfc68&null_safety=true